# Eliminating large plateaus in coarse resolution DEMs?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, resampling

I have a 15-meter, integer DEM I converted into a float raster. However, the original DEM contains large lowland areas that are nearly completely flat. Due to the original resolution and integer format, these flat areas have a step-like appearance with only one meter of difference in elevation despite the large area covered.

How can I correct these large plateaus by smoothing them with a very gentle slope but without touching too much the other features in the landscape?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop but any other free software would be fine.

[image]

Comment: So you want resampling from 15 meters to 2 meters to result in an ***increase*** in data quality? Good luck with that.

Comment: No, I don't want to increase quality. I want to increase smoothness, especially in the flat areas...

Comment: And avoid "stair-step" artifacts... I'm sure it's possible by interpolating contours or elevation points for example. For now I only found the "Topo to raster" tool in ArcGIS that seems to give me some well-tried methods.

Comment: I have to agree with @Vince that going from 15m to 4m pixel resolution is not a good idea, you are just making up data.  You say the original 15m DEM has stepping in the flat areas?  Try converting the 15 meter raster to points, then make a TIN from the points. That will at least give you a slope between the points(cell centers) and not a step.

Comment: I'm aware of the drawbacks of resampling a DEM. The AGREE surface reconditioning method or the Topo to raster tool are able to distort and smooth elevations (i.e. make up data) to produce hydrologically consistent DEMs because the drawbacks of making up data are less than the benefits for the final application. I'm looking for the same kind of solution in the case of large flat areas... Thanks for the TINs, it won't allow for gentle slope though which is the effect I would like to achieve..

Comment: I edited the question. I don't necessarily need a resampling at finer resolution. I can stay at 15-meter resolution in the flat area if needed.

Comment: You could convert your raster to points and then use spline interpolation to get a smooth surface